# How to get the previous hour time with format in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to find the previous hour time with formatting with PS:

I need the below format:

"yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:sstt")

I can use the below code to get the date and time in this format:

```
(Get-Date  -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:sstt")  
2019-09-17-08:45:27AM
```

I  need to get the previous hour time but in the above format

I know how to get  the last hour time :

```
(Get-Date).AddHours(-1)
```

How can i get the previous hour time with a combination of the above 
Format?

Comment: if you add `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:sstt")` to your `(Get-Date).AddHours(-1)` you will get the format you want. as usual with PoSh, there is more than one way to get to your goal ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `-f`, the format operator, as shown in [Ivan Mirchev's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57969725/45375) is definitely an option, and `-f` is a great general-purpose formatting option to know about, for any data type.

However, in your particular case there is a simpler solution, because the [`.ToString()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_) of `[datetime]` instances directly accepts a format string:

```
(Get-Date).AddHours(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:sstt')
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try using the format operator:

```
"{0:yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:sstt}" -f (get-date).AddHours(-1)
```

more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#format-operator--f

Hope it helps! :)